# How to calculate distance from center of a rectangle to sides of the convex hull after rotation?

Tags: math, geometry, algebra, mathematica-8

Knowing the dimensions of the rectangle ABCD, how can we calculate the distances OE and OF after a rotation with an angle=α?[image]

Comment: It is not the convex hull, but the AABB.

Comment: Roughly: Compute all rotated points A', B', C', D'. Compute an axis aligned bounding box that contains those points. Return half of the width and height of this bounding box.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate Bounding box coordinates from a rotated rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622140/calculate-bounding-box-coordinates-from-a-rotated-rectangle)

Comment: The size is W |cosΘ| + H |sinΘ|, W |sinΘ| + H |cosΘ|.

Comment: Sorry I have made a mistake in the image I attached, now I corrected it.

Comment: Yes @YvesDaoust it is as you said : W |cosΘ| + H |sinΘ|, W |sinΘ| + H |cosΘ
but how to calculate this Θ angle

Comment: @MahfoudB.: read alpha.

Comment: @YvesDaoust thank you. Is it in radian or degree?

Comment: @MahfoudB.: that's irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I have fine the answer of my question in a response to this question:
[Find the Bounding Rectangle of Rotated Rectangle [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19830477/find-the-bounding-rectangle-of-rotated-rectangle)

It was written by @MBo like this:

```
Old_Width = X2_Old - X1_Old, Old_Height = Y2_Old - Y1_Old
New_Height = Old_Width * Abs(Sin(Fi)) + Old_Height * Abs(Cos(Fi))
New_Width = Old_Width * Abs(Cos(Fi)) + Old_Height * Abs(Sin(Fi))
X1_New = X1_Old - (New_Width - OldWidth) / 2 = 
         (X1_Old + X2_Old - New_Width) / 2
```